# Is there a JavaScript equivalent for C# 'params'?

Tags: javascript

I need a method that can have an arbitrary number of parameters. In C# we have the `params` statement. Do we have anything similar in JavaScript?

Comment: @Marcin, did not find anything about `params`, you?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is the `arguments` collection, which contains all arguments passed to the function.

There is a) no need to specify "optional" arguments in the function signature and b) any function accepts any number of parameters.

```
function foo() {
  console.log(arguments);
}

foo(1,2,3,4);  // logs [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Likewise, there is no need to supply "required" arguments in a function call:

```
function foo(a, b, c, d) {
  console.log(arguments);
}

foo(1,2);  // logs [1, 2]
```

Any argument named in the signature but not supplied in the function call will be `undefined`.

Note that `arguments` behaves like an Array, but technically it isn't one. For example, you can call `arguments[0]`, but you can't call `arguments.slice()`. What you can do to get around this is using the Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, 2);
```

---

The so-called [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) `...` is a new (ES6+) addition to the language and makes working with variadic functions more comfortable. [@ArunCM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310066/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-for-c-sharp-params/43494575#43494575) explains it.

Answer (score 19):

*I know this thread is too old but I believe something is missing here.*
There is **[Rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)** (*introduced in ECMAScript 6*) which will allow us to represent an **indefinite** number of arguments as an **array**.

**It always returns an array**. Which means even in defensive JavaScript land, it’s ok to do things like check **.length** of rest without guards.
***Syntax :***

```
function(a, b, ...theArgs) {
// ...
}
```

There are three main differences between rest parameters and the arguments object:

1. rest parameters are only the ones that haven't been given a separate name, while the arguments object contains all arguments passed to the function
2. the arguments object is not a real array, while rest parameters are Array instances, meaning methods like sort, map, forEach or pop can be applied on it directly;
3. the arguments object has additional functionality specific to itself (like the callee property).

Additional reading : **[Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)**

```js
function f(x, ...y) {
  // y is an Array
  return x * y.length;
}

console.log("Expected result : 3*2 = 6 & Actual result : " + f(3, "hello", true));
console.log("Expected result : 3*4 = 12 & Actual result : " + f(3, "a", true, "b", 1));

//here we are not passing anything to "y" but its still safe to check .length of "y" because it always return an array.
console.log("Expected result : 3*0 = 0 & Actual result : " + f(3));
```

Comment: I think this should be the expected answer cause it's the true parallel to params (even though not all of us can use ES6)

Comment: @shirbr510 Just keep in mind that you can pass in an array instead of multiple separate objects in C# _and the behavior will be the same_. Where as if you pass an array into a js function using the spread operator instead of multiple separate objects _the behavior will change_. This is due to the static vs dynamic constraints of each language.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `arguments`.

```
function concatStrings () {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        str += arguments[i];
    }
    return str;
}
```

Be aware that `arguments` isn't an array, so it doesn't have methods like `join` or `push`. It's just an array-like object (with numerical properties and a `length` property) so it can be iterated through.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has `arguments` object inside functions. It contains of all params passed to the function.

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Answer (score 1):

It is some sort of implicit in the special variable "arguments". Use like this:

```
function something(arg1, arg2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var x = arguments[i];
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like `something(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c')`

More examples here: http://www.jtricks.com/javascript_tutorials/varargs.html

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions can accept any number of parameters by default. You can see them with the `arguments` variable.

See [here](http://www.davesquared.net/2007/10/passing-arbitrary-number-of-arguments.html).

Comment: It's `arguments`, and it's not a keyword.

Comment: Whoops, my bad, that's what happens when you're doing three things at once. Edited.